# Kubernetes http livenessProbe use https?

Tags: kubernetes

We have an http livenessProbe setup

```
  livenessProbe:
    httpGet:
      path: /admin
      port: http
    initialDelaySeconds: 180
    periodSeconds: 20
```

but why in the description the connection is via https

```
Liveness probe failed: Get https://10.11.1.7:80/admin: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes is doing exactly what you are asking, probing the http url but your application pod web server is redirecting it to https, that is causing the error.

You can either fix that in pod or use [TCP probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-tcp-liveness-probe)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: goproxy
  labels:
    app: goproxy
spec:
  containers:
  - name: goproxy
    image: k8s.gcr.io/goproxy:0.1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    readinessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
    livenessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      periodSeconds: 20
```

Comment: there are no redirects. from another container I get a response `curl -l http://10.11.0.194/admin`. there is no reason to use https

Comment: add scheme: http in the probe

Comment: by default scheme http. and this in deployment.yaml `livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /admin
            port: 80
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 300
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 10`

Comment: 10.11.1.7:80 and 10.11.0.194 IPs are different...are you using any web server like nginx or tomcat?

Comment: no. I made a typo. it's just another container with the same problem